# App crashes on button touch - onTouch method error?

Tags: java, android, button, crash

My app keeps crashing when I click the "startButton". I guess the problem is somewhere within that onTouch method, but I've tried solving the problem for hours; disabling different things inside the `startButton.setOnTouchListener` doesn't make a difference. Can you find anything wrong?

```
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Button startButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView timeLeft = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timeLeft);
    MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.songthingy);


    startButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                mp.start();
                timeLeft.setText("Status: Initiated");
                startButton.setText("Stop");

                startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        mp.release();

                    }

                });

                new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        timeLeft.setText("Status: Starting in... "
                                + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        timeLeft.setText("Status: Finished");
                    }
                }.start();

                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                    }
                });
            }
            ;
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

Comment: These errors are VERY elementary, please code while thinking about flow. Obviously if you don't initialize an object it will be null. Assume simple issues and you will save yourself a lot of time. Also the stacktrace is a dead giveaway that it was null to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exception stack in question, but one issue I see is:

```
MediaPlayer mp;
```

is pointed to `null` and you are calling

mp.start();

in `OnTouchListener`, which results in `NullPointerException`.

I think what you need to do is:

```
 final TextView timeLeft = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timeLeft);
 mp= MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.songthingy);
```

Comment: Agreed, OP should add `mp = ` to `MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.songthingy);`.